# Forcing Download of file using php script on CentOs 5.6

Tags: php

I need to authenticate user to view/download some of the files in my site. My files are located in a folder say A inside `public_html/mySiteName/FoldesName(A)/subFolder/sample.(*.*)`. I used `.htaccess` to check that the user is authenticated or not.

---

MY `.htaccess` code :

```
RewriteEngine on   # Enable rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.*pdf$|.*psd$|.*indd$ [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://MySiteIp/admin_panel/auth.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

My download script looks like :

```
if($authed){

    if(file_exists("../".$_GET['file'])) {
        //Create the pointer to our file and open it as read-only binary data
        $fp = fopen($file,'rb');

        // Send headers telling browser to download our passed data
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo(@fgets($fp, 8192));
        } 

        //Here comes the data 
        fclose($fp);
        //and quit
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "No file exists !!!";
    }
}
```

When I test it on my local machine with Xampp Server installed on it. It works. But on my host I get the error message "NO file exists".

Please help me to find where I am wrong...

Comment: Just a tip, not sanitizing $_GET['file'] will open up a massive security hole. Someone can pass a value like '../../somedirectory/somefile.php' and your script will spit out that file. You should rid $_GET['file'] of slashes at least, before you look up the file.

Comment: Please help to sanitize $_GET['file'].

Comment: Quick and dirty sanitization: `$file = !empty($_GET['file']) ? (str_replace('/', '', $_GET['file'])) : '';` and then use `$file` in your `file_exists()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you removed the `echo "here"; die();` before asking this question.

Anywho, is the file structure the same on your local machine and the web host?

Is the file actually in ../?  Maybe try using the full path to the file? /home/youruser/public_html/ or whatever the host's directory structure is.

Comment: Does your webhost look similar as far as FolderName(A)\SubFolder\ ?

Comment: Try using the absolute path, e.g: `/home/username/public_html/FolderName(a)/SubFolder/file`